# Order of evaluation of bash expression when using vs not using test

Tags: bash

Why does the following script gives different outputs, when the same expression is evaluated with and without `test`? What rules are to be taken into account: operator precedence, left-to-right or right-to-left argument evaluation ...? In my opinion it is important to understand the logic of bash at this basic level.

```
function a()
{
    local r=1
    printf "a%d" $r
    return $r
}

function b()
{
    local r=1
    printf "b%d" $r
    return $r
}

function c()
{
    local r=1
    printf "c%d" $r
    return $r
}

printf "$BASH_VERSION\n" #outputs 4.3.48(1)-release
a || b && c #outputs a1b1
printf "\n"
test a || b && c #outputs c1
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because

```
a
```

runs `a` whereas

```
test a
```

runs `test`, passing `a` as an argument. They're completely different commands.

Similarly,

```
pwd
```

runs `pwd`, but

```
echo pwd
```

runs `echo`, passing `pwd` as an argument.

---

`X || Y` is not an expression, it's a compound command that first runs the `X` subcommand and then (if its exit status is non-zero) runs `Y`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `test` is incorrect in this context. `test` sets the return code to the calling shell by evaluating an expression. The way you've used it, `test a` does not evaluate to an expression but ends up setting a code as `test 1` which  does a string check and always asserts a code 0 (success error code). See

```
test 0; echo $?
0
test 1; echo $?
0
test false; echo $?
0
test true; echo $?
0
```

`test` evaluates the expression `a||b` which sets up a return code `1` to `test` which returns a success error code and runs the function `c` which prints the value you are seeing.

For cases of simplicity, I've changed the function calls to use command `false` which returns error code `1` to the shell as your function.

```
bash -cx "test false || false && echo hi"
+ test false
+ echo hi
hi
```

As you can see, the moment `test false|| false` is run, the command sets success code to the shell and with the operand `&&` the `echo` command is run.

For checking the error code from the function, perhaps you should have checked as

```
test a != "0"
```

See [The classic test command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Comment: In my example, why does test evaluate "a || b", and not "a" nor "a || b && c" ?

Comment: I guess as soon as `||` is encountered, the expression `a || b` is evaluated by `test` and then the result of that is evaluated with `c` with `&&` operator.

Comment: This looks like a strange behavior to me. Maybe someone else can make a guess here?

Comment: OK, test evaluates a's output only (a's output gets eaten up by test), which is true, so b evaluation is skipped (bacause of ||), and then c is evaluated (because of &&), and it's output is not eaten up, so it is sent to console.